# Object not found even though it is globally declared when using geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

R complains about a variable not existing even though it's been declared globally. Here's a snippet of code that reproduces the problem:

```
dataSet2 <- data.frame(FR=c("N", "S", "S","S"))
totalTrx <- 2000
# Errors
ggplot(dataSet2, aes(FR)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = prop.table(..count..) * 100, fill=FR)) +
    geom_text(aes(y = prop.table(..count..) * 100 + 2,label = paste0('(', prop.table(..count..)*totalTrx, ')')), stat='count')

# Runs
ggplot(dataSet2, aes(FR)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = prop.table(..count..) * 100, fill=FR)) +
    geom_text(aes(y = prop.table(..count..) * 100 + 2,label = paste0('(', prop.table(..count..)*100, ')')), stat='count')

# Also runs
ggplot(dataSet2, aes(FR)) +
        geom_bar(aes(y = prop.table(..count..) * 100, fill=FR)) +
        geom_text(aes(y = prop.table(..count..) * 100 + 2,label = paste0('(', totalTrx, ')')), stat='count')
```

Any idea of what's going on here? Using `prop.table` and using a global variable seem mutually exclusive.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with `prop.table` (I can get it to fail w/out it). Just speculating here, but I think that it's actually the use of the derived variable `..count..`, which is created too late in the evaluation process, so when it comes time to finally do the multiplication, the connection between the symbol `totalTrx` and the global environment has been lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to ggplot, not to prop.table
if you define "totalTrx" inside "aes" it is solved.

```
ggplot(dataSet2, aes(FR)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = prop.table(..count..) * 100, fill=FR)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = prop.table(..count..) * 100 + 2,label = paste0('(', prop.table(..count..)*totalTrx, ')'), totalTrx = totalTrx), stat='count')
```